# ¿Cómo crear usuarios a partir de fichero de texto en un script de Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Partiendo de un fichero de texto con los datos de un lote de usuarios que se tienen que crear mediante un script, ¿qué método utilizaríais para **pasar cada dato de cada usuario del fichero de texto a una variable** siendo el contenido del fichero el que sigue?:

```
#Usuario; Contraseña; Grupo; Activo;
us01; abc01.; grupo01; s;
us02; abc01.; grupo01; S;
us03; abc01.; grupo02; n;
us04; abc01.; grupo02; N;
```

El script que tengo creado hasta ahora es el que se muestra en el código a continuación, y la parte que no logro codificar es coger de cada línea del texto el dato concreto (usuario, contraseña, grupo...) eliminando los ";" y almacenarlo en una variable, para así crear un usuario para cada grupo de datos por línea (el problema está indicado al final):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script para crear usuarios a partir de los datos en un fichero de texto
#FUNCIONES---------------------------------------------------------
function crearusuario() #nombre=$1, pas=$2, group=$3, act=$4
{
#Miramos si el grupo existe. Si no existe lo creamos
if grep -q "$3" /etc/group  #existe, por lo que añadimos usuario
then
   useradd -mg "$3" "$1"       #creamos usuario añadiéndolo a grupo
   echo -e "$1:$2" | chpasswd  #creamos passwd a partir del parámetro
else  #no existe, por lo que lo creamos y añadimos usuario
   addgroup "$3"
   useradd -mg "$3" "$1"       #creamos usuario añadiéndolo a grupo
   echo -e "$1:$2" | chpasswd  #creamos passwd a partir del parámetro
fi
}

#PROGRAMA-----------------------------------------------------------
clear
#comprobamos que sea usuario root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]
then
echo -e "El usuario NO es root, por lo que no se permite ejecutar el script"
exit 1
fi

echo -e "Introduzca la ubicación del fichero:"
#bucle de admisión de input
A=0
while [ $A -eq 0 ];
do
read fichero
#comprobamos que el fichero introducido  existe y no está vacío
if [[ -s $fichero ]]
then
    A=1
else
    echo "ERROR: el fichero no existe o está vacío."
    echo "Introduzca de nuevo el nombre y ruta del fichero:\n"
fi
done
#Lectura del fichero línea a línea y asignación a variable
while read -a line
do
  encabezado=$(echo "${line[0]}" |grep "#")  #saltamos el encabezado
  if [ -z $encabezado ] 
  then
  #pasamos a las variables $usuario, $contra, $grupo y $activo los datos
   #EN ESTA PARTE NO SÉ CÓMO PROCEDER PARA QUITAR LOS ;
  usuario="${line[0]}"
  contra="${line[1]}"
  grupo="${line[2]}"
  activo="${line[3]}"
  #creamos el usuario
  crearusuario $usuario $contra $grupo $activo
  fi   
done < $fichero
```

Comment: Buenas, planteé mal la pregunta. La duda es solo la parte del texto, el seleccionar el nombre e introducirlo en una variable, coger la contraseña e introducirla en otra variable... Es decir, el poder seleccionar cada elemento antes del ";".  Todo lo demás no es problema. Eso es en lo que estoy verde.

Comment: @EduenSarceño, lo de actividad era algo que se daba como partida pero no se expicaba...y he buscado y no sé a qué se refería... y tampoco conozco a quién ha puesto eso... así que no es algo que pueda consultar...

Comment: La clave aquí es que puedes parsear la entrada directamente con el `while`, haciendo `while IFS=";" read var1 var2 var3 ... do  ... cosas con $var1, $var2... done < fichero`. Cuando se reabra podré extenderme más.

Comment: Pon la solución como respuesta, y pasados dos días lo podrás aceptar como respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La **SOLUCIÓN** a la pregunta la voy a dividir en partes:

1. Leer un fichero de texto con datos de usuarios separados por ";" y pasarlos a su correspondiente variable (variante1 propuesta por @fedorqui. La más adecuada.):

   ```
    contador=0
    while IFS=";" read usuario contra grupo activo 
    do   
    if [[ $contador -ne 0 ]]  #Para no tener en cuenta el encabezado
    then 
      crearusuario "$usuario" "$contra" "$grupo" "$activo"
    fi
    contador=$((contador+1)) 
    done < $fichero
   ```
2. Leer un fichero de texto con datos de usuarios separados por ";" y pasarlos a su correspondiente variable (variante 2. Permite sacar caracteres de manera individual para cada campo):

   ```
   while read -a line
   do
     encabezado=$(echo "${line[0]}" |grep "#")  #saltamos el encabezado
     if [ -z $encabezado ] 
     then
       #pasamos a las variables $usuario, $contra, $grupo y $activo los datos
       usuario="${line[0]}"
       usuario=$(echo "${usuario//;}") 
       contra="${line[1]}"
       contra=$(echo "${contra//.;}")
       grupo="${line[2]}"
       grupo=$(echo "${grupo//;}")
       activo="${line[3]}"
       activo=$(echo "${activo//;}")
       #creamos el usuario
       crearusuario "$usuario" "$contra" "$grupo" "$activo"
    fi

   done < $fichero
   ```

   Espero que sea de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Imagina que alguna de las variables contiene espacios. Con la versión actual de tu respuesta 1. habría problemas. Sugerencia: añade comillas y di `crearusuario "$usuario" "$contra" ...`

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @fedorqui. Eso lo hago ya dentro de la función "crearusuario" (al principio del código del programa). No sé si hay algún conflicto ahí al hacerlo antes o después...quizá en las líneas 10 y 14 al meter el password...

Comment: Sí, es diferente. Si `$contra` contiene un espacio y dices `crearusuario $usuario $contra $grupo $activo`, internamente se hará `crearusuario $usuario parte_de_contra otra_parte_de_contra $grupo $activo`, por lo que `$grupo` tomará el valor de `otra_parte_de_contra` y `$activo` tomará el valor de `$grupo`. Como ejemplo, prueba a ejecutar `printf "%s - %s - %s\n" "hola que tal"` y compáralo con `printf "%s - %s - %s\n" hola que tal`. El 1º coge toda la cadena como primer elemento, mientras que el 2º coge cada uno separado.